# Tensorflow stack and unstack on a batch to replace channels causes error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So, at one point during my architecture I must replace the 27 first channels of a tensor x (with the shape of (1,32,32,155)) with the 27 channels of a tensor y with (1,32,32,27)

```
    x = tf.unstack(x, axis=3)
    x[0:27] = tf.unstack(y, axis=3 )
    x = tf.stack(x, axis=3)
```

Is what I have settled with. It seemingly works fine for a single image. But as soon as I train my network on a batch of images (in this case a batch of 5). It fails at this point with the error message

```
Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [1,32,32] != values[27].shape = [5,32,32]  [Op:Pack] name: stack
```

When I print the x.shape during a batch training pass, it gives me shape a (1,32,32,155) (printed once for each item in batch); but during unstacking of x, I noticed that the shape of an unstacked element is (5,32,32). As if each of the 155 channels have a batch size of 5.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Maybe, this is not even the correct way to replace elements.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: I had accidentally left a hardocded tensor I used for debugging, which caused the issue. I removed it, and it now works. Though, I still accept suggestions if there exist a better way of replacing than the current way I'm doing it. Thanks

Comment: did u try index slicing and Concatenate layer ?

Comment: try [`tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update)